# Why can't I access the window in Next.js app '_app.js'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, console, window

I have a Next.js app where I want to load the application and then check for Network access with a custom modal dialog that displays if the user disconnects to the internet. I set up an `_app.js` file for my application to set up the Context Provider but unable to check network access on it using the `window.navigator`. It results to an error: "ReferenceError: window is not defined". Is there any way I can load the application first so I can use the custom modal dialog I created?

#### _app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  console.log(window)
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Error upon page reload: 
Approach #1
[image: Error]

Comment: Because, when node tries to compile your next.js app, it couldn't find `window`. Note that `window` is the global object in browsers.

Comment: use window in useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access window when component mounted by using useEffect:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
 useEffect(() => {
        console.log(window)
 },[])
 return <Component {...pageProps} />
```

}

export default MyApp

Comment: I get an error when I reload the page.

Comment: you can also check outside useEffect:
if(window != undefined){
console.log(window)
 }

Comment: What error says?can you comment the error.

Comment: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: I updated and added image above

Comment: My bad. I did not put it inside useEffect